# How can I create a method polymorphism?

Tags: c#

I learn programming oriented object, and I want to do this code but I got those problems, I think I don't really know the concept of virtual.

[View image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALYzj.png)

Code:

```
class Joueur
{
    private string _nom;
    private string _prenom;
    private DateTime _dateDeNaissance;
    private string _position;
    private bool _reserve;

    public string nom
    {
        get { return _nom; }
        set { _nom = value; }
    }

    public string prenom
    {
        get { return _prenom; }
        set { _prenom = value; }
    }

    public DateTime dateDeNaissance
    {
        get { return _dateDeNaissance; }
        set { _dateDeNaissance = value; }
    }

    public string position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set { _position = value; }
    }

    public bool reserve
    {
        get { return _reserve; }
        set { _reserve = value; }
    }

    public Joueur()
    {

    }

    public Joueur(string nom, string prenom, DateTime dateDeNaissance, string position, bool reserve)
    {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.dateDeNaissance = dateDeNaissance;
        this.position = position;
        this.reserve = reserve;
    }

    public double virtual CalculerPrime(int joues, int gagnes)
    {
        double Prime;
        if (reserve == false)
            Prime = 10000 * (gagnes / joues);
        else
            Prime = ((10000 * (gagnes / joues)) / 2);

        return Prime;
    }
}
```

[image: View image 2]

Comment: You need to put virtual before double, so `public virtual double CalculerPrime`...

Comment: oh! yes yes it works, my bad, thank u so mush :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this in your code:

```
public virtual double CalculerPrime(int joues, int gagnes)
    {
        double Prime;
        if (reserve == false)
            Prime = 10000 * (gagnes / joues);
        else
            Prime = ((10000 * (gagnes / joues)) / 2);

        return Prime;
    }
```